# Why does Firefox(Mobile) zoom out of my site?

Tags: html, css, firefox

When I load my webpage in Google Chrome mobile(android), the site loads perfectly, however, when I load the site in Firefox mobile(android), almost every page loads zoomed out. Only once I drop down the menu the site zooms back to normal, if you reload the page, it goes back to zoomed out. This only happens in Firefox.

The site is currently live with this issue:
http://www.iceboss.co.za

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to remember adding this code to the head of your html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will make sure that your website will scale it's width relative to any device that you have.